# Firestore is super slow doing a get command

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to query the data from doc in Firestore for index number and set it as a new doc also set new index number back to the doc querying from but when my function is called it said it took 131909 ms for querying just a doc, It has less than 10 doc in that collection.

This is my code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const request = require('request');
const region = 'asia-east2';
const runtimeOpts = {
  timeoutSeconds: 4,
  memory: "2GB"
};
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.Leave_request = functions.region(region).runWith(runtimeOpts).https.onRequest((request,respond) => {
var userID = request.body.userID;
var profileImage = request.body.profileImage;
var name = request.body.name;
var email = request.body.email;
var office = request.body.office;
var department = request.body.department;
var workplace = request.body.workplace;
var leavetype = request.body.leavetype;
var startdate = request.body.startdate;
var enddate = request.body.enddate;
var reason = request.body.reason;
var num = 0
var newnum = 0
var LeaveID = ""
var getNum = db.collection("Leave_list").doc("Count").get().then(replydoc => {
    if (!replydoc.exists){
        console.log("Not exists")
    } else {

        num = replydoc.data().NumList
        newnum = num + 1;
        LeaveID = "L" + newnum;
        const setData = db.collection("Leave_list").doc(LeaveID).set({
            "userID": userID,
            "profileImage": profileImage,
            "name": name,
            "email": email,
            "office": office,
            "department": department,
            "workplace": workplace,
            "leavetype": leavetype,
            "startdate": startdate,
            "enddate": enddate,
            "reason": reason,
            "status": "Pending"
        })
        var setNum = db.collection("Leave_list").doc("Count").set({
            "NumList": newnum
        })
        push_leave(userID, profileImage, name, email, office, department, workplace, LeaveID, leavetype, startdate, enddate, reason, "Waiting", "#ffc400")
    }
    return null
})
var getAdminUID = db.collection("Leave_admin").where("Headof", "==", "ABCD").limit(1).get().then(snapshort => {
  if (snapshort.empty){
    console.log("No matching documents")
  } else {
    snapshort.forEach(doc => {
      var adminID = doc.id
      push_admin(adminID, profileImage, name, email, office, department, workplace, LeaveID, leavetype, startdate, enddate, reason, "Waiting")
    })
  }
  return null
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
})

respond.send("{}")
function push_leave(toUID, toProfileImage, toName, toEmail, toOffice, toDepartment, toWorkplace, toLeaveID, toLeavetype, toStartdate, toEnddate, toReason, toStatus, toStatusColor) {
//Do the post Request
}
function push_admin(toUID, toProfileImage, toName, toEmail, toOffice, toDepartment, toWorkplace, toLeaveID, toLeavetype, toStartdate, toEnddate, toReason, toStatus) {
//Do the post Request
}
```

I notice that cloud firestore location is further from my country but I think this shouldn't affect so much to the querying time, Maybe it have other factors.

Anyone have any idea to make it reply faster?

Comment: You tagged this google-cloud-functions, so do you have an entire function to share?  It's possible you aren't doing something correctly at a higher level.  Please edit the question to show all relevant code.

Comment: @DougStevenson Sure, I edited it already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is sending the response immediately.  It's not using promises correctly to wait for the database operations to complete before sending the response.  If you send a response before all of the async work is complete, it will possibly terminate your function early, canceling any pending async operations.

Comment: Okay, I see. I thought it will wait for the database operation to complete before sending the response automatically. Now It replies much faster. Thank you.